# Macro to move data from a vertical list to a horizontal orientation

Tags: excel

I believe macros could help make compiling a report every week easier, but I am not very familiar with vba or excel macros. I can add them, but I am unsure of the code.  Thanks in advance for any help.

I have data in an excel spreadsheet with the date in column B and a number in column C. Then the next week's date with its corresponding number below the previous date in column B & C. And so on. So I have on[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCz9v.png)e really long column with the date (Column B) and the number in column c.

What I need is everything with date 1 in Columns B & C, then Everything with the next date in columns D & E, then the next date in Columns F & G. Basically I need the data to go horizontally instead of vertically.

I have attached an example image I hope you can see. I would appreciate any help in creating a macro to quickly adjust my data.

Answer (score 0):

Make a pivot table from your source data.

Put your name field in the Rows area, Date in the Columns. Also drag Date to Values, but change the summarization to Max.  Drag Number to Values.  Turn off all grand totals under the design tab in the ribbon.  You can sort the Date columns newest to oldest to get the newest date on the left.

[image]

Comment: The problem I am running into is the dates are once a week, and this is showing just months. So I am only getting data for the first week.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out - Thank you so much for your help!! This will save me a ton of time